# Keycode, event.which to detect coma and dot and period

Tags: jquery, keypress, keycode

I use this to try to detect coma, dot and period/dot (I don't know if there is a difference there) on both keyboards and numpad.

```
$('.someInput').keypress(function (e) { 
    if( e.which==188){
        alert('coma')
    }
    else if( e.which==190){
        alert('dot')
    }
});
```

It doesn't seem to work.

I also tried 44, 110, 59 (some alternate keycodes I found on the internet) but nothing works.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you inspect the results in your browser `console` what output you've get ? (e.g `console.log(e.which)`)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/st07puvt/ .. click on the window on bottom right hand side and press the key to get the alert